# Custom sidebar nested menu. I cannot open the nested menu

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have the following snippet:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.menu-open').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("data-sidebar-toggle");
    console.log(href);
    href = document.getElementById(href);
    console.log(href);
    $(href).slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav flex-column">
  <a class="nav-link text-light menu-open" href="#" data-sidebar-toggle="#collapseExample"><span>Item 1</span></a>
  <div id="#collapseExample" class="sidebar-menu">
    <nav class="nav flex-column">
      <a class="nav-link text-light menu-open" href="#" data-sidebar-toggle="#item11"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span>Item 1-1</span></a>
      <div id="item11" class="sidebar-menu">
        <nav class="nav flex-column">
          <a class="nav-link"> Hello </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#item-1-2"><span>Item 1-2</span></a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <a class="nav-link active text-light border-bottom-0 border-light" href="#"><span>Item 2</span></a>
</nav>
```

But when I click on the `Item 1` sidebar link item it manages to open and close it, whilst when I click to the `item1-1` link it fails to toggle the `Hello` menu item the reason why that happens is because it fails to get the element having the id defined in `data-sidebar-toggle` attr.

Do you have any idea why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(function() {

  $('.menu-open').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var href = $(this).attr("data-sidebar-toggle");
    console.log(href);
    href = document.getElementById(href);
    console.log(href);
    $(href).slideToggle("slow");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav class="nav flex-column">
  <a class="nav-link text-light menu-open" href="#" data-sidebar-toggle="#collapseExample"><span>Item 1</span></a>
  <div id="#collapseExample" class="sidebar-menu">
    <nav class="nav flex-column">
      <a class="nav-link text-light menu-open" href="#" data-sidebar-toggle="#item11"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span>Item 1-1</span></a>
      <div id="#item11" class="sidebar-menu">
        <nav class="nav flex-column">
          <a class="nav-link"> Hello </a>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <a class="nav-link text-light" href="#item-1-2"><span>Item 1-2</span></a>
    </nav>
  </div>
  <a class="nav-link active text-light border-bottom-0 border-light" href="#"><span>Item 2</span></a>
</nav>
```

Update your code as appear here.You have missed `#` before id(item11).

```
<a class="nav-link text-light menu-open" href="#" data-sidebar-toggle="#item11"><i class="fa fa-user" aria-hidden="true"></i>&nbsp;<span>Item 1-1</span></a>
  <div id="#item11" class="sidebar-menu">
```

This code works. Try this.